# How to set tcp_nodelay in GCDAsyncsocket?

Tags: objective-c, ios, tcp, gcdasyncsocket

Seems like the title is self descriptive. I want to increase the speed of sending and receiving data in my app and i was told to set tcp_nodelay to true. But i have no idea how to do that with GCDAsyncSocket. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did @Martin_R trick help?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't tell you for sure if it helped or not. Seems like it helped at least partly. I have suspended working in that direction due to a range of issues, so frankly speaking, this is my turn to ask you to try that solution and tell me if it helps)))

Comment: I'll return some day and tell you, gotta run some tests firsts :) I'm pretty sure though that having a timeout (not -1) on the writes increases the speed, you should try that.

Comment: thanks a lot for the advice, buddy. i'll be waiting for you writing here and if i make it first i'll write you too

Comment: Hey, It didn't seem to make any difference. Although setting the timeout to 20 as I said before really works. Just make sure that you extend the time for any timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used *GCDAsyncSocket*, but "GCDAsyncSocket.h" shows that you can get the underlying socket descriptor with the `socketFD` method, which must be called only in a `performBlock:` call. So the following code might work:

```
[asyncSocket performBlock:^{
    int fd = [asyncSocket socketFD];
    int on = 1;
    if (setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&on, sizeof(on)) == -1) {
        /* handle error */
    }
}];
```

You might have to add

```
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

to your source file to compile this. As I said, I haven't tried this, but perhaps it helps to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Should this be called for each write or just once after I created the socket?